# Mount Method changed property not maintaining state in other methods

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, livewires

I am changing rule property in mount method. but when i again using rules in other method its not maintaining state. createAccount method is called from button using wire:click.

```
class CreateUsers extends Component
{
    use PasswordValidationRules;

    public User $user;

    protected $rules = [
        'user.name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'user.username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'user.confirm_password' => 'same:password',
        'user.password' => [],

    ];

    public function mount()
    {

        $this->rules['user.password'] = $this->passwordRules();
        dd($this->rule);  // here it is showing updated value
        $this->user = new User();
    }

    public function createAccount()
    {
        dd($this->rule);  // here it is showing default value
        $this->validate();
        $this->user->save();

    }


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.create-users');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use rules property, use the function to add the passwordRules() into and no need to call it in the mount method

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
        'user.name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'user.username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'user.confirm_password' => 'same:password',
        'user.password' => $this->passwordRules(),
   ];
}
```

Comment: yes i used it now. but why it is not working ? why its value getting reset after mount method called ?